# Getting all record by using a reference number in LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have little complication to populate a logic to read few records from my table using linq. Can someone suggest a good option to handle my complication. I have a table like this

```
ContractID, ContractDate, PreviousReference

1           1/1/2012      

2           1/2/2012      1

3           1/8/2015

4           1/3/2015      2
```

I have some contract information in my table. sometime some contact have previous contract reference. In case of previous reference, i need to read all prevoius reference of latest contract. lets say contract id 4, it have 2 reference, so i need to get previous 2 record also.

Is there any option in LINQ to handle such looping

Comment: Currently there is no solution with pure EF LINQ. This is called Recursive CTE, so try to write SQL by the hands.

Comment: SQL will be a nice option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get your Previous References recursively? So if Contract[4] has Previous Reference 2, and contract [2] has PreviousRefercence 1, the if you ask for the previous references of contract [4], do you only want number 2, or also number 1, and all Previous references of number 1? (in your example number 1 has no previous references, but if it had some, would you also want them if you asked for the previous references of contract 4?

Whether you can handle this recursively depends on whether your data is `IEnumerable<...>` or `IQueryable<...>`. In other words: is the data local in your process, or do you have to fetch it from another process, like a database management system?

I'm not sure if this can be done by a DBMS, this depends on whether SQL knows recursiveness.

In local process the solution is not difficult.

So you have a class Contract, similar to the following:

```
class Contract
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public Datetime Date {get; set;}
    public int PreviousReference {get; set;}
}
```

Here the PreviousReferences is like a foreign key to another contract, who can have foreign key to yet another contract, which might have a foreign key to... etc.

You want to have all these Contracts as one sequence of Contracts

For this we create an extension method for Contract. If you are not familiar with extension methods, see [extension methods demystified][1]

```
public static IEnumerable<Contract> GetPreviousReferences(this Contract contract,
    IList<Contract> contracts)
{
    // TODO: implement
}
```

Usage will be as follows:

```
List<Contract> myContracts = ...
Contract contract = myContracts[4];
List<Contract> previousReferences = contract.GetPreviousReferences(myContracts)
                                            .ToList();
```

Implementation is simple if the definition of `PreviousReferences` is clear:

> the collection of PreviousReferences of a Contract is the zero or one PreviousReference of the contract + all PreviousReferences of the contract's previousReference

```
public static IEnumerable<Contract> GetPreviousReferences(this Contract contract,
    IList<Contract> contracts)
{
    if (contract.PreviouseReference != 0)
    {
         // this contract has previous references:
         Contract previousContract = contracts[contract.PreviousReference];
         yield return previousContract;

         foreach (Contract previousReference in previousContract.GetPreviousReferences(contracts))
             yield return previousReferences;
    }
}
```

instead of the `yield return` and the `foreach(...)` you might use LINQ Concat:

```
if (contract.PreviouseReference != 0)
{
    Contract previousContract = contracts[contract.PreviousReference];
    return new Contract[] {previousContract}
           .Contcat(previousContract.GetPreviousContracts(contracts);
}
```

This will do internally the foreach for you. I'm not sure if this solution is better readable.
[1]: http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2013/03/08/c.net-little-wonders-extension-methods-demystified.aspx